# Red Hat Directory Server and LDAP

Tags: rhel, active-directory, openldap

So as the title suggests I have a Red Hat Directory Server with OpenLDAP installed.  I also have Windows Active Directory (mixed network).  I want to script creating new users on the Red Hat Side.

Now if I use `redhat-idm-console` and add a user through that, there is a section where I can checkbox an option to create NT user. There is also a place in there where I can set the NT home drive letter (`H` for example).

That being said I think there is an LDAP command for both but in scouring the web I cannot find out what those commands are.

Does anyone know or have ideas?  FYI I am using an LDIF file to create the user account.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat Directory Server is just a repackaged version of Free IPA server available at freeipa.org this may provide you more sources of documentation with it being the upstream project (still Redhat Inc). Free IPA itself is built on top of the following;

389-Directory Server: Open Source LDAP server Dogtag: PKI CA Server MIT Kerberos: kerberos server SSSD: I don't know enough about to comment on optionally NTP and DNS to add features, a few plugins for 389 directory server and a shiny gui and command line to wrap it all together.

I know it may not help much, but LDAP is all about using LDIF files for creation ldapmodify command doesn't need a LDIF file but as the name says it modifies an existing record.